# Show string instead of numbers in printf (C)

Tags: c, string, int, switch-statement, printf

I've got this code written in C that just on certain number displays a message

```
int main(void) {
int a, d;    
d = scanf("%d", &a);
switch(a){
    case 1:
        printf("ml' nob:\n%d\nQapla'\nnoH QapmeH wo' Qaw'lu'chugh yay chavbe'lu' 'ej wo' choqmeH may' DoHlu'chugh lujbe'lu'.\n", a);
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("ml' nob:\n%d\nQapla'\nQu' buSHa'chugh SuvwI', batlhHa' vangchugh, qoj matlhHa'chugh, pagh ghaH SuvwI''e'.\n",a);
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("ml' nob:\n%d\nQapla'\nqaStaHvIS wa' ram loS SaD Hugh SIjlaH qetbogh loD.\n",a);
        break;
    case 4:
        printf("ml' nob:\n%d\nQapla'\nHa'DIbaH DaSop 'e' DaHechbe'chugh yIHoHQo'.\n",a);
        break;
    case 5:
        printf("ml' nob:\n%d\nQapla'\nleghlaHchu'be'chugh mIn lo'laHbe' taj jej.\n",a);
        break;
    default:
        printf("ml' nob:\n%d\nluj\n", a);
        break;
}
return 0;}
```

But when i enter a string or char in input it gives me a lot of nonsense numbers. Is there a way to show the string that i input in default instead of the numbers.

EDIT:
input

```
abc
```

Output

```
What i want : abc
What it shows: 3469312
```

Comment: I recommend you check what [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns, i.e. the value of `d`.

Comment: Please add an example of input and "nonsense number".

Comment: when i trying your programe which is not show me any nonsense one,

Comment: You should check the return value of `scanf`, instead of just saving it. Also, it sounds like you want to use `fgets` and `strtol`, rather than `scanf`.

Comment: So you want to read a string *or* a number? Then read a string and try to convert it to a number. It the conversion fails then you have a n on-numeric string.

Comment: i have there 5 cases, when you input 1-5 it'll show you the message in case 1-5 and you enter any other number it shows you default message and the number in it but when you enter string in default it shows some numbers but not the string i put it (bcs its int) so my question is if you can put there the string i input in variable "a" instead of the numbers it generates

Answer (score -1):

Try this one..!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(void) {
    int a, d;
    char str[10];
    scanf("%s", &str);

    char* err = NULL;
    a = strtol(str, &err,10);
    if (err==NULL)  //Conversion Error
        a = -1;

    switch((int)a){
    case 1:
        printf("ml' nob:\n%d\nQapla'\nnoH QapmeH wo' Qaw'lu'chugh yay chavbe'lu' 'ej wo' choqmeH may' DoHlu'chugh lujbe'lu'.\n", a);
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("ml' nob:\n%d\nQapla'\nQu' buSHa'chugh SuvwI', batlhHa' vangchugh, qoj matlhHa'chugh, pagh ghaH SuvwI''e'.\n",a);
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("ml' nob:\n%d\nQapla'\nqaStaHvIS wa' ram loS SaD Hugh SIjlaH qetbogh loD.\n",a);
        break;
    case 4:
        printf("ml' nob:\n%d\nQapla'\nHa'DIbaH DaSop 'e' DaHechbe'chugh yIHoHQo'.\n",a);
        break;
    case 5:
        printf("ml' nob:\n%d\nQapla'\nleghlaHchu'be'chugh mIn lo'laHbe' taj jej.\n",a);
        break;
    default:
        printf("ml' nob:\n%s\nluj\n", str);
        break;
    }
    return 0;}
```

Comment: That's a different programming language altogether.

Comment: iostream are included by default.. but none of the program code use C++. And i have edited that C++ part.